# How to create delayed complex objects creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got this problem: 
I have a complex model, Recipe, which have_many Ingredients, belongs_to User, have paperclips images.

I attempt to create some base objects for each new User. For example: a recipe, with it's ingredients (which are differents for each User).
How to create a job to handle these recipes creations? knowing that they must be editable by their users, etc. It's easy for a basic model with no relationships but I'm blocked here...

-I don't want to create Ingredients or Recipe for all users, I want them to be able to delete them.

Here are the params for a single recipe creation by a random user :

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "recipe"=>{"name"=>"Recipe test", "category"=>"Chocolate", "owner"=>"Tom", "baking"=>"100", "note"=>"",
"quantities_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"ingredient_id"=>"6434", "weight"=>"100", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1"=>{"ingredient_id"=>"6681", "weight"=>"10", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "2"=>{"ingredient_id"=>"6668", "weight"=>"210", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "3"=>{"ingredient_id"=>"6591", "weight"=>"100", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "4"=>{"ingredient_id"=>"6611", "weight"=>"20", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "5"=>{"ingredient_id"=>"", "weight"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}},
"process"=>"<p>This is a f*** test of recipe recipe creation</p>\r\n\r\n<p><img alt=\"\" height=\"26\" src=\"http://localhost:3000/assets/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/Emoji Smiley-109.png\" title=\"\" width=\"26\" /></p>\r\n"}, 
"commit"=>"SUBMIT"}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the Recipe and Ingredients as master table and you can create another model like UserRecipeIngredients which will act as join table between User, Recipe and Ingredients. This join table would have `user_id` and `recipe_id` and `ingredient_id` and this model would have the associations like below.

```
belongs_to user
belongs_to recipe
belongs_to ingrdient
```

Comment: I did it with a Quantity table ("quantities_attributes"=>etc), but this is not my problem.. My problem is to create a random recipe for each user with these models. for example : @user.recipe.create(name:"", etc. quantities_attributes: { PROBLEM HERE }) how to handle quantities with no ingredients IDs

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if my question was unclear, I found a solution by defining an ingredient variable :

```
ingredient = user.ingredients.find_by_name("Apricots")
user.recipes.create!([
            { name: "test", category: "Chocolats", baking: "110", quantities_attributes: {"0"=>{"ingredient_id"=>ingredient.id, "weight"=>"100", "_destroy"=>"false"}},process: "try &nbsp;<img alt=\"\" height=\"26\"src=\"http://localhost:3000/assets/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/Emoji Smiley-109.png\""}
            ])
```

Thank you for your help @Jayaprakash & @Thounder

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question correctly but, you shouldn't store fake data in your data base.

If it's for some purpose display, define a method in recipe model which build a fake record with fake many ingredients and call it wherever you want in the

On the other hand, if you want an action to be done after a User record is created, for example, just define an `after_create` callback on your user model